# Rock, paper, scissors game returning wrong results

Tags: javascript, function

I have just started doing the Rock, Paper, Scissors project on The Odin Project and have been really struggling to get a grip on JavaScript in general. I have used a lot of googling so far which I know is fine and have got to this point so far.

```js
function getComputerChoice() {

  const choice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  return choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
}

console.log(getComputerChoice());

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    return `It's a tie! You both chose ${playerSelection}`;
  } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
    return "You win! Rock beats Scissors";
  } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock") {
    return "You win! Paper beats Rock";
  } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") {
    return "You win! Scissors beats Paper";
  } else {
    return `You lose ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
  }
}

const playerSelection = prompt("Can you beat the machine!? Make a choice of either Rock, Paper, or Scissors").toLowerCase();
console.log(playerSelection)
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

My problem is that the results aren't always coming out correctly. For example, the first console log will say the computer chose scissors. The second console log will show the user input of rock, however, the output of the game will return "You lose paper beats rock".

My assumption is that my `computerSelection` variable is creating a second random option which then influences the `playRound` function, rather than storing the original `getComputerChoice` in the variable.

I have tried to google the issue that I assume it is but I am not sure if I am wording it correctly.

Comment: the problem is this line `console.log(getComputerChoice());` when you console.log the function itself along with the parenthesis, you are actually calling the function again which means that the computer gets to make a choice once but then you call the function again and he makes a different choice, changing what he originally had. Remove that line and it will work just fine

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now! I thought it would be to do with that function.

Answer (score 2):

So, like Chris G. said in the comments, you are calling `getComputerChoice()` twice, which changes the output. You are calling it in your first `console.log()` and then at the end where you make `computerSelection`. If you still want to see the computer's choice in the console, change the `console.log` so that it is logging `computerSelection`, which is a variable, not `getComputerChoice()` which is a function. You will also need to move the log to be after the declaration of `computerSelection`, or else you will get an error.

Your code should then look like this:

```js
function getComputerChoice() {
    const choice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    return choice[Math.floor(Math.random()*choice.length)];
}

// console.log(getComputerChoice()); REMOVE THIS

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    return `It's a tie! You both chose ${playerSelection}`;
    } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") {
    return "You win! Rock beats Scissors";
    } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock") {
    return "You win! Paper beats Rock";
    } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper") {
    return "You win! Scissors beats Paper";
    } else {
    return `You lose ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
    }
  }

const playerSelection = prompt("Can you beat the machine!? Make a choice of either Rock, Paper, or Scissors").toLowerCase();
console.log(playerSelection);
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
// ADD THIS:
console.log(computerSelection);
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

Comment: Massive help, thank you!